# What port(s) is used for VS2008 remote debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, remote-debugging

What port(s) needs to be open on the remote machine hosting msvsmon.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385831.aspx) mentions many port numbers that you can open to configure remote debugging. Is this what you need, or are you trying to analyze data being sent over one of these ports?

Answer (score 0):

[How to Enable Remote Debugging on Windows XP Service Pack 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997643.aspx)

...pay attention to steps number 5, 6, 7, and 8.